# Find roots of a polynomial equation or simplify

Tags: mathematical-optimization, polynomials

I have an equation like below:

```
{b (2 - 7 y + 8 y^2 - 4 y^3) + 
   2 y (1 - 4 y^(b/2) + 4 y - 4 y^2 - 2 y^((4 + b)/2) + 
      8 y^(1 + b/2)) == 0 && 0 <= y <= 1 && -15 <= b <= 30}
```

where, `y = Exp{-u/b]`.
I am looking to solve the equation and find the value of `u` in terms of `b`.

which I have been trying to solve using Roots, NMinimize or FindMinimum but none of the options are working. What is best approach to solve this equation?

Comment: Are you looking for $b$ or for $y$?

Comment: @Roman, y. Updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ContourPlot` shows the possible solutions

```
pic=ContourPlot[b (2 - 7 y + 8 y^2 - 4 y^3) +2 y (1 - 4 y^(b/2) + 4 y - 4 y^2 - 2 y^((4 + b)/2) +8 y^(1 + b/2)) == 0, {y, 0, 1}, {b, -2, 1},FrameLabel -> {y, b }]
```

[image]

solution points:

```
{yi, bi} = Transpose[pic[[1, 1]]];
```

solution `u[p]`:

You need an interpolation `y[b]` which is only possible , if you split your datapoints around the maximum of b:

```
ymax = MaximalBy[Transpose[{yi, bi}], Last][[1, 1]]
(*0.168245*)
yb = Interpolation[Select[Transpose[{bi, yi }], #[[2]] >= ymax &]  ] 
(* interpolation yi >ymax*)
```

Now we have to solve `yb[b]== Exp[-u/b]` for b , which gives `u=-b Log[yb[b]]`!

```
Plot[-b Log[yb[b]], {b, Min[bi], Max[bi  ]},AxesLabel-> {b,u}]
```

[image]

The data points `yi<ymax`   are evaluted similar

Comment: Is there anyway to print the values of $y$?

Comment: I edited my answer...

Comment: I am getting the following errors when I tried to run the code: Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of {yi,bi} cannot be transposed.. and MaximalBy::arg1: The first argument is expected to be a list or association.!

Comment: I checked the code in my answer. Reset Mathematica and try again!

Comment: Still not working. however, changing to this: {yi, bi} = Transpose[pic[[1, 1, 1]]]; works.

Comment: Unbelievable! Please check `Dimension[pic[[1,1]] ]`