# Transpose Error

Tags: list-manipulation, mathematical-optimization, warning-messages, interpolation

I have this code:

```
pic = ContourPlot[
  b (2 - 7 y + 8 y^2 - 4 y^3) + 
    2 y (1 - 4 y^(b/2) + 4 y - 4 y^2 - 2 y^((4 + b)/2) + 
       8 y^(1 + b/2)) == 0, {y, 0, 1}, {b, 6, 8}, FrameLabel -> {y, b}]
{yi, bi} = Transpose[pic[[1, 1]]]
ymax = MaximalBy[Transpose[{yi, bi}], Last][[1, 1]]

yb = Interpolation[Select[Transpose[{bi, yi}], #[[2]] >= ymax &]]
Plot[-b Log[yb[b]], {b, Min[bi], Max[bi]}, AxesLabel -> {b, u}]
```

I get an error as below: 
**Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of {yi,bi} cannot be transposed.**
Can anybody please look at the code and let me know why its giving such prompt?

Comment: The ***first*** error I get is `Set::shape`. You should resolve that first. Note that in the `Transpose` error you report, the variables `yi` and `bi` do not have values, which is why the depth-one array `{yi, bi}` cannot be transposed.

Comment: If you set `{yi, bi} = Transpose[pic[[1, 1, 1]]]` all errors go away.  (It's `Graphics[GraphicsComplex[points,...`: need three `1`'s)

Comment: Code runs without error! Clitches can be avoided using `InterpolationOrder->1`
Similar question is answered [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/201563/find-roots-of-a-polynomial-equation-or-simplify)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP's fixed code produces this final plot, which has some glitches:

[image]

Here's an improvement in the interpolation:

```
f[y_, b_] := b (2 - 7 y + 8 y^2 - 4 y^3) + 
   2 y (1 - 4 y^(b/2) + 4 y - 4 y^2 - 2 y^((4 + b)/2) + 8 y^(1 + b/2));
pic = ContourPlot[f[y, b] == 0, {y, 0, 1}, {b, 6, 8}, FrameLabel -> {y, b}];
{yi, bi} = Transpose[pic[[1, 1, 1]]];  (* <-- this where the OP made a mistake *)
ymax = MaximalBy[Transpose[{yi, bi}], Last][[1, 1]];
dyi = -Derivative[0, 1][f][yi, bi]/Derivative[1, 0][f][yi, bi];

yb = Interpolation[
   Select[Transpose[{List /@ bi, yi, dyi}] /. ComplexInfinity -> -20.,
    #[[2]] >= ymax &]];
Plot[-b Log[yb[b]], {b, Min[bi], Max[bi]}, AxesLabel -> {b, u}]
```

> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.

[image]

The derivative at `b == 0` is infinite, which cannot be approximated by polynomial interpolation.  There are two choices, get rid of the derivative value with `ComplexInfinity -> Nothing` or set it equal to an appropriately large value such as `ComplexInfinity -> -20.` (which is actually better than `Nothing`).  For this particular problem the slope should be negative.  Both work.  Beware: if you set the slope too large, for instance `-1000.`, you get a large glitch near `b == 0`, because, again, there's only so much you can do with a cubic polynomial interpolant. (Actually, somewhere around `-20.` is about the best you can do in this case.)